# How to check if a char is equal to an empty space?

Tags: java, char, whitespace

Here's what I've got:

```
private static int countNumChars(String s) {
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()){
        if (Equals(c," "))
    }
}
```

But that code says it cannot find Symbol for that method. I remember Java having a comparer like this... Any suggestions?

Comment: *empty space* - a `' '` with no content?

Answer (score 247, accepted):

```
if (c == ' ')
```

`char` is a primitive data type, so it can be compared with `==`.

Also, by using double quotes you create `String` constant (`" "`), while with single quotes it's a `char` constant (`' '`).

Answer (score 91):

The code you needs depends on what you mean by "an empty space".

- If you mean the ASCII / Latin-1 / Unicode space character (0x20) aka SP, then:

  ```
  if (ch == ' ') {
      // ...
  }
  ```
- If you mean any of the traditional ASCII whitespace characters (SP, HT, VT, CR, NL), then:

  ```
  if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\r' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\x0b') {
      // ...
  }
  ```
- If you mean any Unicode whitespace character, then:

  ```
  if (Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
      // ...
  }
  ```

Note that there are Unicode whitespace includes *additional* ASCII control codes, *and* some other Unicode characters in higher code planes; see the javadoc for [`Character.isWhitespace(char)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29).

---

What you wrote was this:

```
    if (Equals(ch, " ")) {
        // ...
    }
```

This is wrong on a number of levels.  Firstly, the way that the Java compiler tries to interpret that is as a call to a method with a signature of `boolean Equals(char, String)`.

- This is wrong because no method exists, as the compiler reported in the error message.
- `Equals` wouldn't normally be the name of a method anyway.  The Java convention is that method names start with a lower case letter.
- Your code (as written) was trying to compare a character and a String, but `char` and `String` are not comparable and cannot be cast to a common base type.

There is such a thing as a Comparator in Java, but it is an interface not a method, and it is declared like this:

```
    public interface Comparator<T> {
        public int compare(T v1, T v2);
    }
```

In other words, the method name is `compare` (not `Equals`), it returns an integer (not a boolean), and it compares two values that can be promoted to the type given by the type parameter.

---

Someone (in a deleted Answer!) said they tried this:

```
    if (c == " ")
```

That fails for two reasons:

- `" "` is a String literal and not a character literal, and Java does not allow direct comparison of `String` and `char` values.
- You should NEVER compare Strings or String literals using `==`.  The `==` operator on a reference type compares object identity, not object value.  In the case of `String` it is common to have different objects with different identity and the same value.  An `==` test will **often give the wrong answer** ... from the perspective of what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 20):

You could use

```
Character.isWhitespace(c)
```

or any of the other available methods in the Character class.

```
  if (c == ' ')
```

also works.

Comment: Well it ultimately depends on if he is checking for spaces only. I mean if it contains a tab, you would get a false positive.

Comment: Updated.  He can do what he needs directly from Character, although it is overkill.

Answer (score 18):

Since `char` is a primitive type, you can just write `c == ' '`.
You only need to call `equals()` for reference types like `String` or `Character`.

Answer (score 12):

My suggestion would be:

```
if (c == ' ')
```

Answer (score 11):

To compare character you use the `==` operator:

```
if (c == ' ')
```

Answer (score 7):

`Character.isSpaceChar(c) || Character.isWhitespace(c)` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you are thinking of the String comparing function `"String".equals("some_text")`. Chars do not need to use this function. Instead a standard `==` comparison operator will suffice.

```
private static int countNumChars(String s) {
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()){
        if (c == ' ') // your resulting outcome
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
if(Character.isSpaceChar(ch))
{
    // Do something...
}
```

Or:

```
if((int) ch) == 32)
{
    // Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At first glance, your code will not compile. Since the nested if statement doesn't have any braces, it will consider the next line the code that it should execute. Also, you are comparing a char against a String, " ". Try comparing the values as chars instead. I think the correct syntax would be:

```
if(c == ' '){
   //do something here
}
```

But then again, I am not familiar with the `"Equal"` class

Answer (score -5):

To compare `Strings` you have to use the **equals** keyword.

```
if(c.equals(""))
{
}
```

Comment: 1) This Question is about comparing characters, not strings.  2) There is no `equals` keyword in Java.  It is an identifier. 3) Since `c` is a `char` (primitive type!!), you can't call `c.equals(...)`.  4) Even if you could, there is no `char` value that maps to `""`.  The latter means a String with "no characters in it".  That cannot match a character.

Comment: The key to answering this Question is coming up with a meaning for "empty space" that makes some kind of sense in the context.