# Unexpected type error while running charAt in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, charat

While trying to run a small program in java, I'm getting the following error:

```
HangmanSB.java:19: error: unexpected type
            if (sentence.charAt(i) = " "){
                               ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
1 error
```

---

I tried reading the answers to a similar question posted on this website, yet I still can't seem to understand how to fix the error the program is giving me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class HangmanSB {

   public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();

      int turns = keyboard.nextInt();

      for (int turnsLeft = turns; turnsLeft > 0; turnsLeft--){

         int length = sentence.length();

         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){

            if (sentence.charAt(i) = " "){
               System.out.println(" ");
            }

            else {
               System.out.print("_");
            }
         }
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a char is equal to an empty space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510136/how-to-check-if-a-char-is-equal-to-an-empty-space)

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, `==` is the equality comparision operator. You cannot assign something to a function call.

Comment: Compiler complains about assignation `=` instead of  `==`, chars should be enclosed in single quotation too

Answer (score 3):

There are two errors:

`public char charAt(int index)` method returns `char`

and

you need to use `==` instead of assignment operator `=`

Thus use:

```
if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' '){
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your error is here :

```
 if (sentence.charAt(i) = " ")
```

change it to this

```
if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' ')
```

use `==` to compare `int` or `char`

Comment: If I do so, I get the following error: HangmanSB.java:19: error: incomparable types: char and String
            if (sentence.charAt(i) == " "){
                                   ^
1 error

Comment: Also the double quotes are wrong. Needs to be `' '` (a char) instead of `" "` (a string).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' '){
```

Comment: Correct solution, but it is good to provide an explanation as to why this is the fix, so they can learn and understand and avoid the issues in the future

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of errors `=` and `" "`

To compare char value, use `' '` and `==`

Like this :

```
if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' ')
```